# How to run Multiple Magento2 setup with Nginx

Tags: webserver, nginx

I want to configure multiple Magento2 setup (like 3 setups) with single domain name. like..

If I browser the URL as below then it should load separate directory based on Nginx request.

> test.com/m21  > /var/www/m21
>
> test.com/m22  > /var/www/m22
>
> test.com/m23  > /var/www/m23

So can anyone guide me to setup nginx virtual host configuration file which can fulfill my about requirement to load multiple Magneto2 setup over the single domain name.

Waiting for helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's fairly easy to do so in Nginx.
You just have to edit the Nginx virtual host file.

Let's take one case for example.

**Case : One Website, Multiple Store Views**
For example, we have

```
mystore.com (store code: mystore_en)
mystore.de (store code: mystore_de)
mystore.es (store code: mystore_es)
…
```

**Step 1**. Edit your Nginx virtual host configuration file as

File: Usually located under /etc/nginx/sites-available/ or /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/ or other depending upon the OS type.

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    mystore.com mystore_en;
    mystore.de mystore_de;
    mystore.es mystore_es;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mystore.com mystore.de mystore.es;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/your/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;
    include /path/to/your/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Here you can see how the Nginx `map` block is used to set `MAGE_RUN_CODE` as per host. And `server_name` directive includes all the available domains.

**Step 2.** Send MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE variables to the php-fpm server
File: include path from above, example: path/to/your/magento2/nginx.conf.sample

```
#...
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    #add here - start
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    #end

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
#...
```

Here Nginx fastcgi_param‘s MAGE_RUN_TYPE & MAGE_RUN_CODE will create the environment variables for PHP so that the script can access the values via

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']
```

For details please check: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/set-multiple-magento-2-websites-stores-nginx/